# How to display the count in MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, numbers, masm, irvine32

This is my code for a MASM assignment. The assignment is:

> Write an application that does the following:
>
> - Declare a 32-bit integer array with 50 elements with uninitialized values
> - Fill the 32-bit array with 50 random integers
> - Loop through array, and display each value, ***and count the number of negative values***
> - After final loop finishes, display the count

I have it doing everything but displaying the count of negative numbers. If anyone can tell me where I am wrong that would be super helpful. I have been working on this for some time.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myArray SWORD 50 DUP(?)
count DWORD 0
.code
main proc
call randomize
mov esi, offset myArray
mov ecx, lengthof myArray
L1: 
    call Random32
    call WriteInt
    call Crlf
    mov [esi], eax
    add esi, 4
    loop L1

    mov eax, offset myArray
    mov esi, lengthof myArray

L2:
    cmp dword ptr[esi], 0
    jge L3
    DWORD count
L3:
add esi, 4
loop L2

mov eax, count
call WriteDec
call Crlf

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have it doing everything but displaying the count of negative numbers. If anyone can tell me where I am wrong

Firstly, the loop that calculates the count is setting up the registers the wrong way. Instead of:

> ```
> mov eax, offset myArray
> mov esi, lengthof myArray
> ```

you need:

```
mov esi, offset myArray
mov ecx, lengthof myArray
```

And secondly `DWORD count` is not the correct instruction to raise the count by 1. Use `inc count` for that.

### You don't need 2 loops at all

You can and should combine everything is a single loop:

```
  call Randomize

  mov  edi, offset myArray
  mov  esi, lengthof myArray
NextValue:
  call Random32         ; -> EAX
  stosd
  test eax, eax
  jns  IsPositive
  inc  count
IsPositive:
  call WriteInt
  call Crlf
  dec  esi
  jnz  NextValue

  mov  eax, count
  call WriteDec
  call Crlf
```